# How to know what packages I already have downloaded in Octave?

Tags: octave

I just installed Octave a few days ago and think I have been installing packages using the "pkg load name" function but never get a confirmation or anything that looks like the software is trying to download them. I also tried pkg install -forge package_name but that doesn't seem to work. Is there a difference between the two calls?

And; How can I know they are downloading? And where can I find a list of them that are?

Comment: The [manual covers all your asked questions](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Installing-and-Removing-Packages.html#Installing-and-Removing-Packages). TL;DR: `pkg list` shows installed packages, only the `-forge` options "downloads" and installs a package, without `-forge` they are installed using a lokal file. If you want a status while installing, use `-verbose`

Comment: Are all packages installed automatically at download? Cause I see a list of around 30 that I definitely didn't download. Are you sure its just not the list of total available packages?

Comment: Some distributions like the official MXE Installer for windoze already include most forge packages and they are installed together with the core application

Comment: If you used the windows installer all packages are ready to use. A `pkg list` will show you what's there, and `pkg load pgkname` will load it for use. If the list is empty, as it will be if you used the windows zip installer, a `pkg rebuild` will rescan the packages folder and put a new list together.

Comment: So if I want to use call a function in a package I always have to "load" it first even if already installed? I'm not sure MATLAB ever worked that way, it was just "if its downloaded I can call it" lol

Comment: Matlab packages are provided in a limited number by mathworks only while octave packages can be provided by many sources and there are a lot of them. It could make octave dysfunctional loading ALL available packages at once.

Answer (score 2):

The download function and automatic package installation in octave 4.2.1 is broken under windows. Nevertheless the standard packets come with the base installation. Just type
`pkg list`
in the octave console to display all installed packages. In my case the resulting list starts with these lines

```
Package Name         | Version | Installation directory
---------------------+---------+-----------------------
     communications  |   1.2.1 | C:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.1\share\octave\packages\communications-1.2.1
            control  |   3.0.0 | C:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.1\share\octave\packages\control-3.0.0
     data-smoothing  |   1.3.0 | C:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.1\share\octave\packages\data-smoothing-1.3.0
           database  |   2.4.2 | C:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.1\share\octave\packages\database-2.4.2
          dataframe  |   1.1.0 | C:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.1\share\octave\packages\dataframe-1.1.0
...
```

To get package information programmatically use

```
[dummy,info]=pkg('list');
```

`info` is a cell array of structures containing information about the packages. You can e.g. read the information about name and load state:

```
>> info{1}.name
ans = signal
>> info{1}.loaded
ans = 0
```

To get help about the package function enter `help pgk` on the command line. This help is currently (Octave 5.1) not included in the html documentation. That means `doc help` does NOT display this help page.

[octave](/questions/tagged/octave) [windows](/questions/tagged/windows)

Comment: With pkg list I can read the listing by eyes, but it is not so easy in the program.
The structure is not so simple and I could not find out how to index the table cells correctly in order to find "package name", and check, if there is an asterisk, or other indication of "loaded" state.

Comment: The function call  `[dummy,info]=pkg('list');` provides all information nicely in a cell array of structures. You can iterate through info using commands like `info{1}.name` to get the name or `info{1}.loaded` to get name and state of a package. By the way: why do you need to check state of a package. Normally it is sufficient to just issue `pkg load ...` in the functions where you need it. The execution time is relatively short if the package is already loaded.

Comment: Yes, I can when I know the exact index. But using ":", and substituting it to string comparison functions seems (to me) not possible with simple {#} indexing. I get "a cs-list cannot be further indexed". So I have to traverse every single cell in FOR cycle, and conditionally check ".loaded" field. That is not so elegant as Octave usually allows. And no so fast, so there is no benefit of checking the loaded state before executing load in every program cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information about listing the current packages `pkg list`. It was useful to me: +1